# Explain why any coset in $R$ can be written as $g+\langle f \rangle$ where $\deg(g) \leq 2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $f=x^3+x^2+x+2 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}_3[x]\langle f \rangle$.

1. Explain why any coset in $R$ can be written as $g+\langle f \rangle$ where $\deg(g) \leq 2$.
2. Then explain why $g+\langle f \rangle \neq h+\langle f \rangle$ if $g\ne h$ are polynomials of degree less than or equal to $2$.
3. Lastly use the results of the above question to determine number of elements in $R$.

I am confused on the first question. My intuition for the second question is to show that $g-h \notin \langle f \rangle$. IS this correct?

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to show $x^3$ is linearly dependent on $1, x, x^2$. But clearly

> $$x^3 = -x^2-x-2= 2x^2+2x+1$$

So now if you have any $x^n, n>2$ write it as $x^3\cdot x^{n-3} = 2x^{n-1}+2x^{n-2} +x^{n-3}$, so by induction and the well-ordering principle, we can reduce any degree polynomial to an equivalent one of degree at most $2$.